# Who is the person checking into rehab as Lindsay?

Tags: arrested-development

In S3E12 of Arrested Development ("Exit Strategy"), Lindsay and Lucille tell Michael they're checking into rehab, while they actually go to a spa instead. In their place, they send two other people to rehab in their place:[image: rehab]

The woman on the right, pretending to be Lucille, is clearly her housekeeper Lupe. But *who is the woman on the left pretending to be Lindsay?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Arrested Development* wiki has a [page for this episode](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Exit_Strategy) that describes her as "a younger Latino woman, possibly Lupe's daughter".  This exact wording is repeated in the Wikipedia article for the episode and in many other pages presumably from the same source.  However, the [NPR page](http://apps.npr.org/arrested-development/episode-s03e12.html) for this episode describes her simply as "Lupe's daughter", without any hint of uncertainty.

Comment: When Buster visits Lupe at home, he sees old clothes and his hand chair that he used to wear. The fact that the woman on the left wears one of Lindsay's tops strongly suggest she's at least part of Lupe's family.